# Oracle on Linux with ASP.NET Windows Authentication Impersonation

Tags: asp.net, oracle

Can someone please direct me on how to do this type of setup, i.e. I have a Windows Server with ASP.NET pages and would like to pass those credentials using Integrated Windows Authentication to a Linux-based Oracle DB.

Comment: Hi, It's been more than 5 years since you asked this question. Do you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting

```
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="false" />
```

In the web.config. This should send the credentials of the end user through to the database. If this isn't what you want, then try something like

```
ImpersonableWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

CredentialCache creds = new CredentialCache();
NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("bob", "130B", "domain");
creds.Add(new Uri(url), authType, networkCredential);   

request.Credentials = creds;
```